# python list being interpreted as an integer; counting inversions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

Getting error:

```
File "inversions.py", line 26, in merge
if left[i] < right[j]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

My implementation of merge sort is like so; accepts a list and it's length. Base case is when length is 1, where I simply return the list (not as an int, but as a list):

```
def mergesort(arr, length):
    if length == 1:
        return arr
```

Working of merge sort function in non-base-case situation:

```
    n = length // 2
    left = arr[:n]
    right = arr[n:]

    lsort = mergesort(left, len(left))
    rsort = mergesort(right, len(right))
    result = merge(lsort, rsort, length)

    return result
```

Then there's the merge function for merging two sorted sub-lists, defined like so:

```
def merge(left, right, length):
    buff = []
    i = j = count = 0
```

This merge function is obviously called by the merge sort function after all recursive calls are done.

There are if-else statements in this merge function that handle it's working:

```
    if left[i] < right[j]:
        buff.append(left[i])
        i += 1

        if i == len(left):
            for j in range(j, len(right)):
                buff.append(right[j])
            break

    elif left[i] > right[j]:
        buff.append(right[j])
        j += 1

        count += len(left) - i

        if j == len(right):
            for i in range(i, len(left)):
                buff.append(left[i])
            break
```

In the end, this merge function returns 'count'; number of inversions.

Judging from the error, it seems that 'left' etc are being interpreted as integers, thus giving me the subscript error. But I just can't understand WHY they are ints when clearly they should be lists (or maybe I'm just missing something very obvious).

I just can't get my head around this. Any and all help is appreciated! :)

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Paste the reorganize code here directly; as text. If it's long, you need to produce a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Sorry! New here. I've edited it. Thanks :)

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show actual assignments to local names. With no assignments you cannot determine where integers are assigned to names `left` and `right`. Please show [MCVE].

Comment: _In the end, this merge function returns 'count'; number of inversions._ it smells like you may trying to use return value of this function somewhere where actual sequence is expected.

Comment: @Łukasz Rogalski I added more info! 'actual sequence is expected' hmm but I thought the variable 'result' would just take on the int value as opposed to the list it takes usually! Tbh I did just copy my implementation of merge sort and tried modifying it!

Comment: They are not "interpreted" as integers, they actually *are* integers. The issue, then is where your assignment to the variable is assigning an integer rather than a list. Python does not "interpret" your data, unlike say php.

Comment: @dsh Yes, you're right! I did realise my mistake in the code. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your code, and in `merge` function you're returning the variable `count` of type `int` and then passing it to `merge` again as array in the recursion.
So the block `if left[i] < right[j]:` won't work.

Change `merge` function to return `buff` variable.

Comment: oh sh*t yeah! Thanks a lot I just realised it, how I'm failing all the recursion steps. I was imagining just a 2 level recursion tree while writing this and I never thought of the recursions in the middle!

Comment: You're welcome. I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072004/understanding-the-recursion-of-mergesort) will help you visualize the process.

Comment: oh, amazing! Thanks again haha! :)