# MergeSort using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I am a beginner and trying learn about recursion, I have tried going through tutorials and old Q & A here in Stackoverflow to understand better but couldn't be able to..
Can anyone enlighten me how recursion works by using following MergeSort snippet.

```
public class MergeSort{
public static void main(String a[]){
    int [] array={5,2,8,4,7,3,9,1};
    mergeSort(array,0, array.length-1);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  System.out.print(array[i]+"  ");
  System.out.println();
 }
}
public static void mergeSort(int array[],int low, int high){
  if (low >= high) 
      { 
           return;
      }   
   int middle = (low + high) / 2;          
   mergeSort(array, low, middle);
   mergeSort(array, middle + 1, high);
   merge(array, low,middle,high);
 }
 public static void merge(int arr[],int l,int m,int h)
 {  \\Remaining Code goes here..}
  }
```

Comment: check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072004/understanding-the-recursion-of-mergesort

Comment: Recursion works by calling the same method on a subset of data over and over again until you've broken the larger task into a single task.  Look into a factorial example.  It's a perfect sample of code explaining the basic concept of recursion through a simple solution.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt simple explanation !Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I will not stick very close to the snippet - it is more important to understand the general concept.

- An array with only one item is sorted "by default". This is the condition used to terminate the recursion, here the `if (low>=high)...`
- An array with more than one element is split up into a left and a right half. Each of the half is sorted by recursively calling `mergeSort`
- After each of the halfs is sorted, they need to be merged, in your case by a call to `merge`.